# Mono.Cecil Modifying the RVA of a method

Tags: mono.cecil

I would like to modify the RVA of a method using Mono.Cecil. I noticed a similar question asked back in 2007 but is this doable in 0.95?

For eg: methodA.RVA = 0x1234;

I understand Mono.Cecil compute and write RVA during compilation but
are there anyways to go about modifying the RVA?
It can be done using CFF explorer though.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible: that's simply not the goal of Mono.Cecil.

Cecil let you read, modify and write the managed code and metadata, but when it comes to the PE file organization, that's considered an implementation detail.

Comment: Thank you for reply. it's not for malicious purposes though.

Comment: Is it possible to get a method's metadata offset using mono.cecil? I understand that i may have to go through the PE/net headers but would like to ask if mono.cecil can retrieve them. (just like IL instruction offset). Thanks